# python hlookup lookup function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have two data frames like this, and I want to merge `df2` with information from `df1`

`df1`

```
Topic1  Topic2  Topic3  
Aa        Bb      Cc  
Dd        Ee      Ff  
Gg        Hh      Ii
```

`df2`

```
My_topics    
Topic2
Topic3
Topic1
```

The desired output is

```
My_topics   Word1  Word2  Word3 
Topic2      Bb      Ee    Hh
Topic3      Cc      Ff    Ii
Topic1      Aa      Dd    Gg
```

I used `lookup` functions, but could not get the desired output.

```
df2['Word1'] = df1.set_index('I dont know what put here').lookup(df2['My_topics'],df2['My_topics'])
```

Comment: Show your own code, describe exactly what "not works" means, show errors or wrong output (properly formatted in the question). Add tag for the library you are using (pandas?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df1
  Topic1 Topic2 Topic3
0     Aa     Bb     Cc
1     Dd     Ee     Ff
2     Gg     Hh     Ii
>>> 
>>> df2
  My_topics
0    Topic2
1    Topic3
2    Topic1
```

you can issue

```
>>> df3 = pd.concat([df2, df1.reindex(columns=df2['My_topics']).T.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
>>> new_names = {i:'Word{}'.format(i + 1) for i in range(len(df1.columns))}
>>> df3.rename(columns=new_names, inplace=True)
>>> 
>>> df3
  My_topics Word1 Word2 Word3
0    Topic2    Bb    Ee    Hh
1    Topic3    Cc    Ff    Ii
2    Topic1    Aa    Dd    Gg
```